# Creating different "distributions" of an project

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am switching (or at least trying to) from Ant to Maven.
I am building a complex project, resulting in one WAR file, expanded into a single folder.

Then, in Ant I am creating 10 different "distributions", which means I copy some propertie files, CSS and HTML files from a "config/" directory to the folder, create a  and repeat the step with the next "config/" folder.

In the end, I have 10 ZIP files with customized ressources for each customer.

The and code looks like that (might not be the best ant code, but works perfectly):

```
<!-- Distributionen -->
<target name="distribution-customer1" depends="jar-with-dependencies">
    <property name="dirname" value="customer1" />
    <antcall target="distribution">
        <param name="dirname" value="${dirname}" />
    </antcall>
</target>
<target name="distribution-customer2" depends="jar-with-dependencies">
    <property name="dirname" value="customer2" />
    <antcall target="distribution">
        <param name="dirname" value="${dirname}" />
    </antcall>
</target>
<target name="distribution-customer3">
    <property name="dirname" value="customer3" />
    <antcall target="distribution">
        <param name="dirname" value="${dirname}" />
    </antcall>
    <!-- Startdateien mit Port 8080 statt Port 80 -->
    <copy todir="${root.dir}/distribution/${dirname}/" overwrite="yes">
        <fileset dir="${root.dir}/configs/${dirname}/" includes="myproject_starten**" />
    </copy>
    <!-- Nachdem wir Dateien geändert haben, nochmals WAR und ZIP generieren -->
    <antcall target="create_war_and_zip">
        <param name="dirname" value="${dirname}" />
    </antcall>
</target>
<!-- /Distributionen -->

<!-- Über Antcall aufrufen, nicht direkt! -->
<target name="distribution" depends="jar-with-dependencies">

    <!-- Altes Verzeichnis löschen -->
    <delete dir="${root.dir}/distribution/${dirname}/" />
    <!-- Neu anlegen -->
    <mkdir dir="${root.dir}/distribution/${dirname}/" />
    <!-- Alles vom Template rüber kopieren -->
    <copy todir="${root.dir}/distribution/${dirname}/" overwrite="yes">
        <fileset dir="${root.dir}/distribution/myproject_template/">
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <!-- Service.ini mit der Version aus dem individuellen Config-Verzeichnis 
        überschreiben -->
    <copy todir="${root.dir}/distribution/${dirname}" overwrite="yes">
        <fileset dir="${root.dir}/configs/${dirname}/">
            <include name="*.ini" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <!-- Alte Propertydateien löschen -->
    <copy todir="${root.dir}/distribution/${dirname}/myproject/WEB-INF/classes" overwrite="yes">
        <fileset dir="${root.dir}/configs/${dirname}/">
            <include name="*.properties" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <!-- ggf. Log4J Config überschreiben -->
    <copy todir="${root.dir}/distribution/${dirname}/myproject/WEB-INF/classes" overwrite="yes">
        <fileset dir="${root.dir}/configs/${dirname}/">
            <include name="*.xml" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <!-- Custom CSS kopieren -->
    <copy todir="${root.dir}/distribution/${dirname}/myproject/assets/css" overwrite="yes">
        <fileset dir="${root.dir}/configs/${dirname}/assets/css/">
            <include name="*.css" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <!-- Custom Images kopieren -->
    <copy todir="${root.dir}/distribution/${dirname}/myproject/assets/images" overwrite="yes">
        <fileset dir="${root.dir}/configs/${dirname}/assets/images/">
            <include name="*.png" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <!-- Daten kopieren (Falls vorhanden, für Demo)-->
    <copy todir="${root.dir}/distribution/${dirname}/data" overwrite="yes" failonerror="false">
        <fileset dir="${root.dir}/configs/${dirname}/data/"></fileset>
    </copy>

    <copy todir="${root.dir}/distribution/${dirname}/myproject/bilder" overwrite="yes" failonerror="false">
        <fileset dir="${root.dir}/configs/${dirname}/bilder/"></fileset>
    </copy>

    <delete file="${root.dir}/distribution/${dirname}/readme.internal.md" />

    <antcall target="create_war_and_zip">
        <param name="dirname" value="${dirname}" />
    </antcall>

</target>

<target name="copy-to-distribution" depends="jar-with-dependencies">
    <delete dir="${root.dir}/distribution/myproject_template/myproject/" />
    <mkdir dir="${root.dir}/distribution/myproject_template/myproject/" />
    <mkdir dir="${root.dir}/distribution/myproject_template/myproject/bilder" />
    <mkdir
        dir="${root.dir}/distribution/myproject_template/myproject/bilder/details" />
    <mkdir
        dir="${root.dir}/distribution/myproject_template/myproject/bilder/originals" />
    <mkdir
        dir="${root.dir}/distribution/myproject_template/myproject/bilder/thumbnails" />
    <copy todir="${root.dir}/distribution/myproject_template/myproject/">
        <fileset
            dir="${build.dir}/dist/${ant.project.name}-with-dependencies-jar/" />
    </copy>
</target>
```

How can I do something like that with maven? 
Should I use profiles?
Should I even use maven for that task?

Any help is welcome!

Thank you,
schube

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you want from us, because we're certainly not going to port your entire Ant file to Maven. But yes, using profiles seems like the way to go. "Should I even use maven for that task?" That's opinion-based. You certainly *could*.

Comment: Hi @Michael! What I want? A pointer in the right direction, I do not expect anyone to port my ant file :-)
The thing is, I read https://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/ which says, one should not use profiles.
On the other hand, I think my usecase with "custom distributions" is not that of an exception and there should/must be a recommended maven way and I am looking for it. So I just need a "go the profile way" or "do not use it, go the XY way for this usecase". Thank you!

Comment: I recommend to look at https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [war-overlays](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) here is an example:

A parent pom, to hold all the child projects together:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
  <artifactId>war-overlay-example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>base-war</module>
    <module>dist1-war</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

A base war that project, for any common stuff:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
        <artifactId>war-overlay-example</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>base-war</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>base-war</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

And as many distribution wars to change anything in the base-war. Anything included in this project will replace anything in the base-war. You can have nothing and get the full base-war or insert individual files.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
        <artifactId>war-overlay-example</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>dist1-war</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
            <artifactId>base-war</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>dist1-war</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <overlays>
                        <overlay>
                            <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
                            <artifactId>base-war</artifactId>
                        </overlay>
                    </overlays>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Working example [here](https://github.com/gregclinker/war-overlay-example)

Comment: Thank you! I think that is what I need! Will definitely try it ASAP! And big big thanks for the github example! More than I asked for!